# Google API and map.panTo: not panning

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, navigation, panning

I'm trying to improve my sound project site, but I'm stuck in... panning.

I have a Google map populated by markers, associated to a text and a recorded sound. It works. I'm trying to allow user to navigate map through panning, by I can't get my map panning.

I'm not an expert in php or Google API and this is my first post here, hope it's well formatted.

The web address of the project is soundplaces.net

I've created a function map_panning(), and then tried to call this function with

```
<a href="" onclick="map_panning()">please PAN</a>
```

in content div.

The map just reloads... even if I tried to place a "return false" in the function.

I also tried to make the map pan when a marker is clicked

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); map.panTo(marker.getPoint());  
      });
```

But still, does not work.

Can anybody help me?

This a greater part of the code I have in my default.ctp (the site is made with CAKE), hope it helps.

```
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $CenterMap; ?>), 13);
map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
GDownloadUrl("http://www.soundplaces.net/xml.php", function(data) {
  var xml = GXml.parse(data);
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
var description = markers[i].getAttribute("description");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var file_name = markers[i].getAttribute("file_name");
    var marker = createMarker(point, name, description, address, type, file_name);
    map.addOverlay(marker);


      }
    });
  }
}

function createMarker(point, name, description, address, type, file_name) {
  //var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
  markerOptions = { icon:soundIcon };
  var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br />" + description + "<br />" + "<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='/media/dewplayer.swf?mp3=/media/audio/"+file_name+"' width='200' height='20'><param name='movie' value='dewplayer.swf?mp3=media/audio/"+file_name+"' /></object>";
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); map.panTo(marker.getPoint());  
  });
  return marker;
}


function map_panning() {
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(44.433373,10.712251));
    return false; //cancel navigation
}
```

Then in body

```
   <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">



        <div id="content">
        <a href="" onclick="map_panning()">Please PAN</a>
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>

            <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>

        </div>
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up a combination of Google Maps API 2 and API 3 code.  The two don't work together, you have to use one or the other.  API 2 is deprecated, so you should preferably use API 3.

e.g. `new google.maps.LatLng(44.433373,10.712251)` is API 3 but `new GMarker(point, markerOptions)` is API 2.

And if you did want to keep it all with API 2, you should probably amend your map_panning function to be something like:

```
map.panTo(new GLatLng(44.433373,10.712251));
```

Comment: Thanks very much Duncan! I'll try and let you know about it!

Comment: Actually, doesn't work yet. It seems like the map is unresponsive. The site was written in API 2, so I've tried to keep 2 syntax. I'll keep trying to find where I go wrong.